# Is it possible to run this command in Amazon AWS? xargs -n 1 curl -O < files.txt

Tags: node.js, curl, amazon-s3

Is it possible to run the following command in amazon aws?

```
xargs -n 1 curl -O < files.txt
```

Downloading all the files from the Web by taking the URLs from `files.txt`

Is there any way to run this command in Amazon AWS and transfer the files into S3 Bucket? Or is it possible to write some code in `node.js` or any other language to achieve this. Please give me any references.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the following command in amazon aws"? Are you referring to running it on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance? If so, please note that this is a Linux question, and is unrelated to the fact that it is running on AWS.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Is it "I have a list of URLs in a text file and I want to put the content of those URLs into Amazon S3", just like your previous question: [Is there any way to upload 50000 image files to Amazon S3 Bucket from a list of URLs - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482735/is-there-any-way-to-upload-50000-image-files-to-amazon-s3-bucket-from-a-list-of) ?

Comment: I'm new here. My apologies for not following Stackoverflow rules. Yes @JohnRotenstein Exactly. This is what I want to achieve. As the `Amazon S3 bucket` can be mounted to `Amazon EC2 Linux instance`, I'm referring to running the above command in Amazon EC2 Linux instance. Is it possible?

Comment: While there are utilities that can mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a virtual drive, it is not a recommended way of using S3. The better method is to use the Amazon S3 API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that you have posted three questions that are pretty much the same, I'm going to assume that you want to take a list of URLs from a textfile, download the content, and then upload them to S3.

Here's the type of program you could use (written in Python):

```
import urllib
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

# Read a file of URLs (For example: http://example.com/happy.jpg)
file = open('urls.txt', 'r') 

for url in file: 
    # Download the URL, save it in a file called 'object'
    urllib.urlretrieve (url, 'object')

    # Upload the file to Amazon S3
    s3_client.upload_file('object', 'my-bucket', url[url.rfind("/")+1:])
```